# sbt (building Scalatra) immediately fails with <2GB of RAM

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra

I set up a DigitalOcean "droplet"/server and provided it with 512mb of RAM. upon trying to run the ./sbt script I instantly get this failure:

> Using /root/.sbt/0.13.0 as sbt dir, -sbt-dir to override.
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000a0000000, 1073741824, 0) > failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>   # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1073741824 bytes for committing reserved memory.

1073741824 bytes ~= 1.07GB. If I bump it up to 1GB of RAM, it fails, but it works when I provide 2GB to the server.

I have seen similar questions, but all answers were along the lines of "provide more space"...but is that normal? Why does sbt require that much memory allocated *instantly*? It doesn't seem to need that much when its actually building. Is it possible/wise to change how much memory sbt tries to allocate?

Answer (score 0):

You may set memory allocation pool's limit by providing `-Xmx` option to JVM. To achieve that, edit your sbt script like it said in [sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Setup-Notes.html#JVM+heap%2C+permgen%2C+and+stack+sizes).
Another way - setting swap or adding more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The `sbt` file in (Scalatra) project directory has a setting `$default_sbt_mem` which is set to 1536. You can change it depending on your server.